# ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre tú, usted y vos?

Tags: traducción, selección-de-palabras, pronombres

He oído las palabras `"tú"`, `"usted"`, y `"vos"`, pero la traducción de todas esas palabras al inglés es la misma: `"you"`.

¿Cuándo es mejor usar `"tú"` o `"vos"` en vez de `"usted"`, o viceversa?

Comment: There is a discussion here whether we should Q&A written fully in Spanish: http://meta.spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/1/should-we-allow-question-and-answer-bodies-in-spanish

Comment: Just a comment.
In Central America we use *vos*.

Comment: El salvador usamos vos usted ustedes nosotros

Comment: En mi país Costa Rica y otros países de Latinoamérica es casi ridículo usar el "tú". Aquí utilizamos el "vos" cuando uno se dirige a una persona con la que lo une un vínculo familiar o de amistad, y el "usted" cuando no son personas con ese tipo de vínculos.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

- **TÚ**:
  Se usa con amigos, con todos los parientes (puede haber excepciones) y en situaciones **informales**.
- **VOS**: Solo se usa en ciertas partes de Latinoamérica, principalmente en Argentina, Uruguay, Guatemala y algunas otras partes de Centroamérica y Sudamérica (Chile, Colombia, partes de Bolivia). Todo el mundo sabe hablar de "tú", pero no todo el mundo sabe hablar de "vos".
- **USTED**: Se usa con personas en situaciones **formales**: desconocidos, con gente mayor/ancianos, con personas con un título, Dr. o Dra., profesor(a), "señor(a), señorita", don o doña, etc.
- **VOSOTROS**: Solamente se usa en España (excepto Canarias y Andalucía oriental). Se usa en situaciones informales, es el plural de "tú". En España solo se usa "ustedes" como plural de "usted".

No se usa *VOSOTROS* en Latinoamérica; se usa "tú" o "vos" para el singular informal; y "ustedes" para el plural formal.

No se usa *VOS* en España; se usa tú (singular) y vosotros (plural) para situaciones informales. Son más dispuestos en España a usar "tú" en situaciones en las que un latinoamericano quizá usaría "usted". (En partes de Sudamérica, principalmente en Colombia, pero también en lugares en Venezuela donde el uso de usted reemplace "tú" completamente. Este fenómeno se llama "ustedeo")

---

Vos ([Voseo dialectal americano](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/?key=voseo)) es una forma única y especial; viene del pronombre arcaico vos (voseo reverencial) que antes se usaba para decir "tú" y "vosotros" que se conjugaba igualmente para los dos (No había otra manera de distinguir). Ej.: "Vos tenéis" significaba tanto "tú tienes" como "vosotros tenéis", dependía del contexto.

Ahora, la forma de vos (voseo dialectal americano) tiene conjugaciones diferentes. Antes era "tenéis" y ahora es "tenés", "habláis", "hablás", "sois", "sos" etc., pero depende del país. En Chile y otros lugares se conjuga diferente ya que se aproxima más al antiguo voseo reverencial.

Comment: También se usa vosotros en Guinea Ecuatorial, no es solo de España.

Comment: En Venezuela también se utiliza el "vos" en la región zuliana.  En la región andina, es mucho más común usar "usted".  Una nota interesante se consigue en el portugués de Brasil, dónde se emplean "usted, você, y tú": el "tú" se utiliza sólo en círculos íntimos (familia, amistad).

Comment: En Argentina "vos" es un tratamiento igualitario mientras que "usted" es respetuoso.  
En cambio "tu" prácticamente no se usa.

Comment: @David "tu" en portugués no tiene acento y sólo es usual en el sur del país y en Rio de Janeiro.

Comment: @AlanEvangelista gracias por tu aclaratoria, mis amistades brasileiras son the Brasilia, Rio de Janeiro, y São Paulo .

Answer (score 18):

La primera distinción que haría es con "vós": es muy común en el español latinoamericano, pero no se usa en el peninsular (el de España). Por lo tanto, en España es mejor evitarlo completamente.

El uso de "tú" y "usted" es más complicado. Hablaré por el uso en España, que es el que conozco.

En teoría se usa "usted" con todas las personas adultas, pero en la práctica lo normal es usarlo sólo con la gente desconocida de cierta edad o en situaciones formales. Por ejemplo: con ancianos, con jefes, con sacerdotes (están muy acostumbrados a ser tratados con un cierto respeto, heredado de tiempos pasados en los que tenían más poder del que tienen ahora ;-)), con vendedores y dependientes, en reuniones de trabajo (e incluso ahí está pasando de moda y se prefiere "tú"), etc. Donde NO se usaría: con tu abuela, con el dependiente de tu tienda de ropa habitual, con cualquier persona que te presenten durante una fiesta o una reunión de amigos, etc.

Se puede usar "tú" con cualquiera menor de treinta años sin problemas, e incluso con gente de más de treinta y de cuarenta (o más aún) si es una situación informal. Muchas veces se considera que el uso de "usted" implica que no queremos acercarnos demasiado (emocionalmente) al interlocutor, y puede ser considerado un trato seco y frío, bordeando la mala educación. También puede ser considerada mala educación usar "tú" con la gente equivocada, por un exceso de confianza.

Ejemplos de mal uso: un señor con dinero que trata a un hombre de su edad pero menos afortunado (un camarero, un chófer, etc.) de "tú" le está haciendo un desprecio porque está insinuando que es menos importante que él, o que es de clase baja, como un criado; un profesor que trata a un alumno de "usted" está marcando las distancias, cerrando la posibilidad de que haya un trato amistoso entre ambos, quizás porque lo considera indigno o despreciable.

Ante la duda, lo mejor es usar "usted" sólo con gente mayor (de más de cincuenta años, por ejemplo). Siempre habrá gente de más edad que prefiere el trato de "tú", y lo dirá así ("tuteame, por favor"), y siempre habrá gente de menos edad que prefiere el trato de "usted"; pero en caso de error, "tú" está mejor considerado.

Por otro lado, en ciertas partes de España usan "ustedes" como si fuera "vosotros". Por ejemplo: "¿a dónde vais ustedes?" No es 100% correcto gramaticalmente, pero está tan establecido que se considera normal. Lo he oído sobre todo en el sur, en Andalucía, pero creo que en otras regiones (Canarias, por ejemplo) también se usa.

No sé si con esto he conseguido aclararte la duda o te he confundido más :-) Pregunta si no ha quedado claro algo, por favor. Nunca consigo explicarme demasiado bien O:-)

Comment: Adonde vais ustedes es un barbarismo.

Answer (score 8):

Tanto "tú", como "vos" como "usted" significan "you" (en inglés). Son la segunda persona del singular. Pero lo importante es tener en cuenta la formalidad y la región.

Si es formal, se debería usar "usted".
Si es informal, dependiendo de la region se debería usar "tú" o "vos".

Comment: Advertencia: "Usted" es pronombre de segunda persona, pero se conjuga en tercera persona.

Answer (score 4):

The differences between the usage of the three words actually varies a lot from country to country and generation to generation.

In Mexican Spanish "vos" is never used but you will begin to hear it in Guatemala and it's well known in Argentine Spanish.

[The Wikipedia article on *voseo*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voseo) provides some introduction into the complexities and extent of the usage variations.

Comment: As a native Argentine speaker this is correct. "Usted" it's only used formally (to show respect to elder people or business). "Vos" is the usual way here otherwise. I believe this is only in Argentina and Uruguay, not the other Spansih speaking countries.

Answer (score 3):

The reason why you get the same result when translating to English is simple, they mean *you*.

However let me explain  the differences:

*Usted*
Is regularly used to denote respect to the person you are talking to; this could be your elders, someone older than you or simply someone who inspires your respect. For instance let’s say you are talking to a priest and you want to tell him that he is very smart:

> Sacerdote, es usted muy intelilgente.

Now let’s say you are in school and you want to tell your classmate that he is very smart:

> Amigo, tú eres muy inteligente.

Now, in regards  to *tú/vos* they are basically used on the same context, however *vos* is mostly used South America, *tú* is more common in Spain and in North and Central American countries like Mexico.

Comment: Also, English used to have "thou" as the second person singular, but this usage is now archaic. Many centuries ago, tú would have translated to "thou", but in modern English, this is no longer the case.

Answer (score 3):

My Spanish is from Guatemala. We use *usted* as formal way just like everywhere else. *Tú* and *vos* are both used but they have their place.

*Tú* in Guatemala is a used for endearment (romantic or family love) and would never be used on a pal. Its more for a lover or a mother to a child. If I used tu with a pal they would call me a fruit (*afeminado*). If I used it on a girl I didn't know, I could get slapped in the face.

*Vos* in Guatemala is a little more rough but not formal. It might be used were the person is at equal stature. Example: a trucker would use it with another trucker, a school mate to an other, etc.

Comment: que interesante. Pasa lo mismo en Honduras? (yo no uso Vos asi que no tengo idea de estas cosas)

Answer (score 2):

Vos se usa en castellano clásico y equivale a "tú". "Vos sois inteligente" significa "tú eres inteligente", "vosotros" es el plural y equivale a "ustedes" y si se usa mucho en España, Argentina, Bolivia y donde existe el idioma castellano.

Comment: Esta respuesta es incorrecta. 1) "Vos sois" es un arcaísmo, mientras que "vos sos" o "vos eres" son formas actuales en muchas regiones hispanohablantes. 2) "Vosotros" prácticamente no se usa en Argentina (y otras regiones), al punto que hay gente que ni siquiera sabe conjugar bien esa forma. La segunda persona del plural en dialecto rioplatense es "ustedes" tanto para "vos" como para "usted". Otras respuestas lo aclaran.

Answer (score 1):

En Argentina no se usa "tú" (que es el pronombre *legal*).
Usamos "vos" y "usted".

El "vos" es un tratamiento confianza, entre pares y amigos. Y los verbos se declinan de una manera diferente, como en la respuesta de @lanzipants.

El "usted" en cambio denota formalidad o respeto y se usa con gente mayor, de más jerarquía o desconocidos. Los verbos se conjugan como en tercera persona.

Ejemplo: el médico diría ...

- a un amigo: "vos tenés fiebre".
- a un paciente: "usted tiene fiebre".

Si bien "vos" proviene de una forma respetuosa de referirse al otro, ahora y acá es lo contrario.
Estando en Argentina, usás "vos" (como estoy haciendo ahora) libremente con tus *compañeros*: los que viajan o trabajan con vos.
En cambio usas "usted" siempre con la policía, el empleado administrativo que está del otro lado del mostrador (especialmente si no es joven).
Podés usar "vos" con los jóvenes de 20 o 30 años.
Y seguramente tratarás de "usted" a Vito Corleone. 
Tené en cuenta que si escribís como yo ahora el corrector ortográfico va a protestar todas y cada una de las veces que pongas una de estas conjugaciones (como me está pasando ahora).