# Why do we use different words for "Usted es un niño" and "Tú eres un niño"?

Tags: selección-de-palabras, gramática, subjuntivo, expresiones

Why do we use "es" for "usted" and "eres" for "tú"?

Comment: tú y usted is equivalent to the vous-tu in french. Tú is like an informal you (friends, couple, someone that you trust) and usted is like you (your boss, and acquaintances, people that you respect).

Comment: Related: http://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/7/12, http://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/836/12, http://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/1427/12

Comment: I encourage you specifically to read [this question](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/1427/12) and its answers, as it explains how Usted is used, grammatically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usted is equivalent to you (2nd person) in English but it uses the third person form of the verbs (like he, she, it) in Spanish.

presente verbo es:
yo soy
tú eres
él es
nosotros somos
vosotros sois
ellos son

Usted must use 'es'.

Answer (score 13):

The word *usted* is derived from the ancient expression *vuestra merced* (*your mercy*), which was used to politely/formally address other people several centuries ago. When you addressed someone as *vuestra merced*, you were not directly addressing them, but something else ("their mercy"); hence the use of the 3rd person that has been kept to our days.

Many other languages resort to using the plural in their courtesy treatments, such as French (*vous*) or German (*Sie*). Even English, though this is masked nowadays. Originally, *you* was the plural of *thou*; but it was used so often as a courtesy treatment that the singular form (*thou*) was deprecated in regular use. This is the reason why, nowadays, English makes no difference between the singular and plural forms of the 2nd person.

Comment: Very nice answer.

Comment: Very nice indeed.  If you're not careful, @Gorpik, people will think you actually know what you're talking about instead of just making stuff up like everyone else does here.

Answer (score 3):

"Tú" and "Usted" are the second personal-pronoun. Both of them.

We use "Tú" for friends, siblings, people of our age, sometimes younger people than us, or someone that we have confidence with,

With "Usted" we refer to older people than you, professors, maybe your parents and older familiars, or someone you don't have that much confidence with. It shows some respect for the person.

"Es" and "Eres" are the conjugation of the verb "Ser" ("To be"). We use "Es" with "Usted" and "Eres" with "Tú".